# how to get a valid url for pinterest share on wordpress site

Tags: php, url, share, pinterest

My URL for pinterest sharing is coming back as invalid. Getting this error:

> Parameter 'method' (value link) is not one of unknown, uploaded, scraped, bookmarklet, email, iphone, button, ipad, android, android_tablet, api_sdk, extension, api_other, bad.

I don't understand why this is happening, as the URL that is generated is correct. My code is:

```
<?php
    $postpermalink = urlencode( get_permalink() );
    $featureImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large-thumb');
?>

<a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=<?php echo $postpermalink ?>&amp;media=
    <?php echo urlencode($featureImage[0]);?>&amp;description=<?php the_title() ?>" target="_blank">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/core/images/pinterest-icon.png" alt="Pin it" 
width="26px" height="26px" title="Pin it"/>
</a>
```

In the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

My circumstances were somewhat different, but I ended up at this page looking for an answer to the same question. I'm guessing the problem is the lack of data-pin-do and data-pin-config attributes in your anchor.

I got things to work by following [Pinterest's guide](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/) *exactly,* then carefully working my way towards generating my own URLs and visuals.

I also got errors when testing locally, but not on a remote server. Obviously sites need to be able to reach a server to get information, but Pinterest is obnoxious; Facebook and Twitter will do their best with what they can get vs. just throwing an error.